# R source() not working, but script runs fine otherwise R-4.2.2

Tags: r, rstudio

As stated, the problem is pretty clear cut. I have an R script which cannot be run by using `source()` but it runs fine if I paste the entire script into the console. I have R-4.2.2, but I am unable to currently update my RStudio at the moment---although I suspect updating that might fix the issue.

Here is a small working example:

```
library(quantmod)
getSymbols("TQQQ")
x <- as.numeric(TQQQ$TQQQ.Close)
d <- (x[2:length(x)]-x[1:(length(x)-1)])/x[1:(length(x)-1)]
dl <- log(x[2:length(x)]/x[1:(length(x)-1)])
curPrice <- tail(x,1)
nsims <- 10^2
endPrice <- numeric()
N <- 71
```

When I run the above code in console and with `source()`, it works fine. Then I simply add the line `for (k in 1:nsims){}` and it breaks!

```
library(quantmod)
getSymbols("TQQQ")
x <- as.numeric(TQQQ$TQQQ.Close)
d <- (x[2:length(x)]-x[1:(length(x)-1)])/x[1:(length(x)-1)]
dl <- log(x[2:length(x)]/x[1:(length(x)-1)])
curPrice <- tail(x,1)
nsims <- 10^2
endPrice <- numeric()
N <- 71
for (k in 1:nsims){}
```

The above code works fine when pasted into console, but not with `source()`.

When I first load `quantmod` I get the error:

> Warning message: R graphics engine version 15 is not supported by this
> version of RStudio. The Plots tab will be disabled until a newer
> version of RStudio is installed.

So I am wondering if my `source()` problem has something to do with the plots tab or otherwise the graphical system?

Even if updating my RStudio fixes this issue, it still seems like something that should receive attention from the RStudio developers since it is so strange.

===

**UPDATE:** issue appears fixed and was due to the offending R script file being *empty* on local disk (and in cloud backup) but not empty in the RStudio script editor!!!

I don't totally understand how this happened. Somehow the R script file opened in RStudio was disconnected from the version on local hard disk. I think this may have been a Google Drive error as that's where the file was being saved/backed up. I can't totally figure it out though.

I updated RStudio, and then re-opened the offending R script file and it was *blank*!!! So that could explain why running it with `source()` was literally behaving like running an empty file.

Given that the `source()` command behaved the same in default R console and in RStudio console, I don't think it was a problem with R or RStudio. It could have been an RStudio problem with how the script editor was saving the file, but that seems unlikely. I swear I uploaded the exact same file to rstudio.cloud and it was functional there and not empty. I feel that user error with file location is the most likely and sensible error, but I swear that I checked that carefully even renaming the file and saving it. The test file that I was using in the above MWE was *not empty* though.

Comment: When you say "it breaks," what exactly happens? Do you get an error? Does R hang?  What version of RStudio are you running? Does the problem persist if you run the code in the standard R GUI? I cannot replicate any issue when running it myself.

Comment: Your code is working fine with R 4.2.2 on Rstudio (tested on mac)

Comment: @MrFlick it literally just returns nothing in the console. No error, nothing. No variables added to environment. I just enter the source command and hit return. It is as if the text command registered nothing and like I just got enter for a new line.

Comment: What exactly does your call to `source()` look like? Have you tried this in R itself rather than going through RStudio? Do you get the same effect?

Comment: I'm just using the source button in RStudio, but it is source('<file address>', Echo=TRUE). Maybe it was double quotes though. I'm now on my other machine and it all works fine (which is updated). Works fine on RStudio Cloud too (which is obviously updated).

Comment: Oh, it also didn't work when I just ran it in the R-4.2.2 console outside of RStudio. But it seems to be machine specific.

Comment: It just happened once in R-4.2.2 console (not RStudio), but didn't repeat... strange...